# Closing socket and its resources

Tags: c++, eclipse, sockets

I'm closing socket using the `close()` function. After I saw it didnt work (by debugging) I tried also the `shutdown()` function. But still I saw that the socket value didnt change.
Anyone cn tell me what may be the reason for a socket not to close and what is the value of a socket that was close.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work" ? What happened ? Why did you expect a socket value to change ?

Comment: I dont know exactly - thats why I asked for the value of a scoket that was closed. And i know it didnt work becasue I treid running the program again and the port was taken

Comment: You were inspecting the number of the socket handler? Are you referring to the ``int close(int fd)`` POSIX function? If the answer is true, change the C++ flag into C and rephrase a bit, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `close` function closes the socket. The port may still be taken by connections that haven't shut down yet. If that's an issue, look at the `SO_REUSEPORT` option.

Comment: the port can still be used even if i closed all the sockets that were using it?

Comment: @sdfdg56 Yes. TCP connections take time to tear down.

Comment: Thank you! i didnt know that. I thought there was something wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the POSIX function

```
#include <unistd.h>
int close(int fd);
```

and you do something like:

```
int socket_handler;
// initialize everything
// ...
close(socket_handler);
```

Then look carefully and you will see that the `close` function does not (cannot) change the value of the `socket_handler` variable.

You have to check if the socket is closed by other means --like @DavidSchwartz has already answered.